# CSS background-image is distorted and zoomed in on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have two background images on my website, both with CSS. The initial landing page image works perfectly on both desktop and mobile, however the second one is distorted in Safari. I have tried every solution I've found online but nothing works.

The landing image was originally distorted but I found a solution for it online, which works perfectly and is the following (just in case it's relevant):

```
'''
    <div class="home-wrap">
        <div class="home-inner">
        </div>
    </div>
'''

'''
.home-wrap {
    position: fixed; 
    top: -50%; 
    left: -50%; 
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;
}
  .home-inner {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    z-index: -100;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .home-inner {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url('../images/bgmob.jpg'); 
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      background-color: black;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
 }
'''
```

The following is the second background image which is distorted:

```
'''
    <div class="bg-wrap">
        <div class="fixed-background">
        </div>
    </div>
'''

'''
.bg-wrap{
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.fixed-background {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(../images/bg2.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .fixed-background {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('../images/bg2mob.jpg');
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        position: fixed; 
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
 }
'''
```

I know Safari mobile browsers don't respond well to backgroung-image but I figured if I got the first one to work the second should work too. I feel like it might have something to do with the positions.I also have smaller, more mobile friendly images for mobile browsers which are visible in the above media queries. I've tried countless solutions so this is my last desperate attempt.

Comment: Not saying the positioning is not the issue (look up relative and absolute positioning) but the distortion comes from the fact that you are setting both the height and width. If you set one or the other ( for most cases height works best on mobile width on desktop) cover should allow it to size correctly. Also try using vh(viewport height) and vw(viewport width) instead of % on height or width

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to just height: 100vh; however the image is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `background-size: cover;`? Because that will stretch the image to fill the whole div.